# UISlider not working, only display half of the track

Tags: ios, uislider

Upon inserting a UISlider into my interface, I am greeted with something immediately strange to me in the Interface Builder, Half of the track is gone. I figured this was a graphical glitch, because those are quite common with the interface builder so I decided to preview my application. The same issue was present. So, I ran my application to find out that not only was the issue present, but the UISlider was not responsive in any way, shape, or form. I tried moving the Slider out of the nested view to make sure that nothing was blocking touch events to it, although to no avail.

The reason that I say that `Half of the track is hidden` can be seen in this picture below:

[image]

As you can see by the selectors, the UISlider is only taking up half of the space it should be, on-top of that it still has it's default values:

- Minimum: 0
- Maximum: 1
- Current: 0.5
- Mode: Scale To Fill
- Enabled: true

Now the strange part is that I know there's nothing wrong with `UISlider` as a whole, because I use it in other interfaces/views. This can be seen working below:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here, as I can't find any reason that the UISlider should not work. I'm not using any Custom views or ViewControllers in this interface, it's just... not working, and for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

try to set `minimumTrackTintColor` of the `UISlider`with any other color. It may be taking clear color or background color(white). And that's why not visible to you.

Comment: Strange, I wonder how that happened, however the issue about the Slider not working at all persists.